# How to check if a word fits in specified number of columns?

Tags: python, string

so I've been asked to write a code that asks the user to input the maximum number of columns (width of a line) and then let the user input a paragraph. now if the last word in each line doesn't fit in the line then i have to move it to the next line and replace it with spaces in the previous line. I wanna know how can I check if a word fits in the line or not and if it doesn't how can i print it on the next line. Here is my code:

```
    max_num=int(input("Enter the maximum number of columns for printing: "))
    paragraph = input("Enter your paragraph:\n")
    paragraph = input()

    word_list = paragraph.split(" ")


    counter = 0
    while (counter < len(paragraph)):
        a = paragraph[counter:counter+max_num]
        counter+=max_num

        print('|'+str(a)+'|')
```

Answer (score 2):

And if this is an exercise, the coolest way would be to use the dynamic solution for [the word wrapping problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap#Algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't an exercise, the easy way would be [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html).

Comment: actually its an exercise and I'm not supposed to use textwrap. I have to use split though